# Get content from Drupal Views with JSON

Tags: json, drupal, view

I have build Views that show some images from nodes. I'm also using Views Datasource plugin for Views. It prints me a JSON result. Now the problem is.. quite silly and simple in a way but for some reason I don't get my head around it: when user clicks link on page I should get the content from nodes using that view and it's JSON but I don't how to do it.

So when user clicks link, it should activate that view somehow? And then with ajax I'll go and get the content. I know how to get the content with ajax and stuff like that but the "activitation" is the problem :D

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to generate the url or link of the node along with the images in views so that when clicked on the image it fetch the associated node content